# Return View from ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionFilter that checks if a parameter in the URL is valid.
If it is not valid I have to render a View. I dont want to redirect, because I still need the ActionExecutingContext.
Can that be done?

```
    public override void  OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Guid processIdentifier = (Guid)filterContext.RouteData.Values["processIdentifier"];
        //if processIdentifier  not found render a view with message and some other objects in ViewData
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("WrongProcessIdentifier", "The process-id you supplied is not valid");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`HandleErrorAttribute` had what I was looking for.

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "MessagePage",
                ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
                TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
            };
```

Comment: I think you should accept your own answer because it includes code

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I intentionally did not include code, since this area of code is changing with every release of the MVC framework right now. I think the correct answer is "do whatever the framework is currently doing."

Comment: If you need to set the model, it's part of the `ViewData`. `ViewData.Model`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look at the source for HandleErrorAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[HandleError]
public ActionResult MyAction (int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

And put the view you want rendered in to `~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx`.

Comment: Filters like [HandleError] apply only to action methods.  The OnActionExecuting() method is itself a filter rather than an action method, so attributes like this have no effect.